# Ubuntu server 11.10 and PHP 5.2 for use with Drupal 6

Tags: php, ubuntu, drupal-6

I'm trying to figure something out:

I am using Ubuntu server 11.10 virtualized on Win7 (I don't think that matters but more info is better than less) to work on a Drupal 6 website I inherited and need to make significant changes to.

I want to set up a development copy of this Drupal website on my Ubuntu server so I can work without worrying about torching the production website.

I successfully got the production files downloaded and onto my machine, I got the production MySQL database exported and imported into the dev MySQL server, and I set up a symbolic link from the directory /home/myname/thewebsite.com to /var/www/thewebsite.com so I can easily access it.

When I got the website they didn't know the admin password so I dug around online and reset it in the dev db using phpmyadmin and finally log in.

When logging in and poking around the site there are lots of errors, which when googled lead me to believe that PHP 5.3 is causing them and that there are some modules in use that only work with PHP 5.2

After looking around a lot online and on stackoverflow there seems to be no easy way to install PHP 5.2 on Ubuntu Server 11.10. With no packages for 5.2 available through apt-get or aptitude what should/can I do?

1) Install 5.2 from source - how do I get it to interface with MySQL and Apache2? Also, I've never installed anything significant from source. Is there a walkthrough?

2) Replace the repositories with old ones? Will this work on 11.10? The newest instructions I found were for 10.04

3) Use already built PHP 5.2 packages for Ubuntu? Couldn't find these

4) Pay someone who knows more to do it for me? (Just kidding, this isn't really an option...)

Cheers and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP dropped support for 5.2 in August 2011; operating system providers such as Ubuntu will not supply a version that is out of support, so you absolutely won't get an official copy of PHP 5.2 on the current version of Ubuntu (or any other OS).

If you're running an older version of Ubuntu (eg 10.04), you might be able to do it; it would still be a downgrade, because PHP 5.3 has been the default version for quite a long time now.

If you're on a newer version of Ubuntu, ie 11.10 as you state, it is going to be a problem for you.

The Drupal developers dropped the ball badly on this one. I guess it was because Drupal 7 tool so long to finish; they were expecting D7 to be out much sooner, and so they never bothered fixing up D6 to work with PHP5.3. As it turned out, this was a big mistake, because in fact D7 still wasn't officially released when PHP dropped support for 5.2.

But even so, they should have fixed it, because they're still officially supporting Drupal 6, so they need it to work with the current version of PHP. This is definitely Drupal's problem, not PHP's, Ubuntu's or yours.

But you still need to deal with it.

I found [this question over on AskUbuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61101/downgrade-php-to-php5-2), which gives an answer applicable to 11.04. It isn't quite 11.10 you were asking for, but it it a lot more recent than the best you'd found, so it might be helpful.

Alternatively, you could research exactly what it is about Drupal6 and your specific modules that doesn't work in PHP5.3. The language differences between 5.2 and 5.3 that can break things are not big, so I would expect any code changes required to be fairly small. You might find you can fix the code yourself. And maybe even submit the changes to the community -- Drupal is open source, after all.

Another tack you could take is to consider whether this saga represents an opportunity for you to move the site to Drupal 7?

This may or may not be feasible, depending on the modules you're using, etc, but if it is possible, it will solve the problem, because D7 is of course fully compatible with PHP5.3.

And just to cheer you up, I'll close by mentioning that PHP are on the verge of releasing PHP 5.4. Hopefully the Drupal devs will be more on the ball this time.

Comment: This answer is great. It pointed me in the exact direction I needed and avoided the mess of compiling PHP 5.2 from source as well as informed me **why** this issue is happening. As a note, to install from the new repository using the command line, I found out you can do `sudo apt-get install -t {repo name} package1 package2` etc